# How do I disable cloudflare image optimization?

Tags: image, optimization, cloudflare

I use cloudflare for my website www.yopisode.com. The image quality on the website is poor. How do I get the original image quality? I would wish to bypass cloudflare image optimization or image caching. I have put it on CDN only and even used the temporary development mode, but nothing is working.

Answer (score 0):

If Mirage or Polish are causing issues, then you can turn those features off in your [Performance Settings](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168206-How-do-I-access-my-CloudFlare-Performance-Settings-).

Note: Caching really wouldn't impact image quality. I wouldn't recommend disabling that.

Comment: Thanks very much. OK, these are two words which I have seen in blog posts and help documents 'Mirage' & 'Polish'. I don't see them on my performance profile/settings page. https://www.dropbox.com/s/nxz42m0pjcapmek/performance%20setting.PNG?dl=0 Am I on the right page?